# R interactive and batch mode and the heIp browser

Tags: r, cran, rapache, rserve

When running R in 'batch mode', the `interactive` flag is set to false, which prevents any sort of user prompts that would interrupt the process in the context of an embedded/batch setting. See:

```
R -e 'interactive()'
```

Some holds when using `Rscript`. The flag can also manually be set by using the [interactivity](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/interactivity/index.html) package. To test, we can try:

```
R -e 'install.packages("anything")
```

Assuming no CRAN mirror has been set yet, `install.packages` will not show some interactive mirror picker, but instead throw an error and exit.

However, I noticed that the `help` or `?` command will still work. For example, the command below will show the help browser, and it does not continue until I press q.

```
R -e 'help(lm); 1+2'
```

However, when sending the output to a file, it does not show the interactive prompt and just dumps the complete help document in the output:

```
R -e 'help(lm); 1+2' > output.txt
```

I'm a bit confused now about what is really going on when using `help`. Why do you get the interactive help browser even when R is running in batch mode? Is this a feature of `R`, or from the Debian/Ubuntu front-end? Is there a risk of `R` becoming unresponsive when the `help` function is called inside i.e. Rserve, RInside, JRI, etc, due to R waiting for using input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

help actually spawns a new process, pager, which is like "less":

```
> help(lm); 1+2
[1]+  Stopped                 R -e 'help(lm); 1+2'
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
27735 pts/6    00:00:00 bash
31607 pts/6    00:00:00 R
31615 pts/6    00:00:00 sh
31616 pts/6    00:00:00 pager
31617 pts/6    00:00:00 ps
```