# R: issue with interactive mode

Tags: r, r-markdown, rscript, interactive-mode

I have followed th[is tutorial on R blogger](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/02/making-r-files-executable-under-windows/) to create a file extension `.Rexec` to be able to run scripts on double click, without opening RStudio. The script is supposed to do the following :

1. Select file to be used as data input
2. Select the decimal separator
3. Render a `.rmd` with the two above elements as parameters.

At some point, I succeeded to run the script and generate a report. But now, for an unknown reason (I did not update R (which is R-4.2.2patched) nor RStudio (2023.06.1 Build 524) since then), RScript now executes the script in batch mode instead of interactive mode.

`test.Rexec` is the following:

```
    interactive()

    readline(prompt="What is your First name ?")

    datainput<-choose.files()

    rmarkdown::render(
      input="test.rmd",
      params=list(datainput=datainput))

    for(i in 1:100) {
      cat(".")
      Sys.sleep(0.01)
    }
```

`test.rmd` is the following:

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    output: html_document
    params:
      datainput: 
        input: file
        value: "test.txt"
    ---

    ```{r}
    read.table(
      file=params$datainput,
      header=TRUE,
      sep="\t")
````

`test.txt` is the following:

```
    x   y
    1.5 2.1
```

When double clicking on `test.Rexec` , I can see that `interactive()` returns `FALSE`, which confirms that the problem is likely related to the `interactive` mode. I can select a file, but any other interactive function such as `select.list` or `readline(prompt="...")` results in an unexpected termination of the process when it is reached. The `render` function also induce a crash, making the whole thing unusable.

`test.rmd` is rendered perfectly when I execute each line of `test.Rexec` one by one in the console of RStudio.  I read on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037082/r-interactive-and-batch-mode-and-the-heip-browser) that there was a [package interactivity](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/interactivity/) that allowed to change this, but it is now archived.   Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354736/how-to-run-r-script-containing-interactive-user-options-from-a-batch-file) tried creating a file `test.bat` with the command :

`echo source("C:\Users\...\test.R") | R.exe --ess --vanilla` without success. Replacing `` `R.exe` `` by `RScript.exe` and `Rterm.exe` with and without `--vanilla` also resulted in failure.

The user is not supposed to type any command in a terminal/console by himself, so suggesting to type execute from a command is not an option in this case.

I guess that if you follow the same protocol as explained above, things should go fine. I don't know what I may have done to mess up with RScript and I am therefore unable to reproduce the problem.  Did someone had the same issue ? Can someone explain to me how to execute my script in interactive mode so it runs as expected ?